# Identify all overlapping Highcharts scatter points clicked by the user

Tags: highcharts, scatter

I have a highstock chart with a scatter series that has overlapping points. The X values are identical but the Y values have slight variations. Because the variations are small the overlap is not exact but is still difficult for the user to distinguish.

When a scatter point is clicked / tapped I want to identify all data points that the mouse pointer / finger touches. However it seems like Highcharts will only raise a click event for the point on top of the stack. There are several suggestions online for iterating over all data points and finding those with matching Y values, however in my case I would need to apply some fuzzy logic and try and select points that look to the user like they're overlapping, based on the size of the marker and the height of the chart and this seems like a move in the wrong direction.

Is there anything within Highcharts I can use to find all the points the user interacted with?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f22tq4t2/1/

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'Demo scatter overlap',
        data: [{x: 1500052112000, y: 5}, {x: 1500052112000, y: 5.1}, {x: 1500052118000, y: 15.1}, {x: 1500052118000, y: 15.2}]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        min: 1500052109000,
        max: 1500052119000,
        type: "datetime"
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: (event) => {
                        alert('clicked ' + event.point.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Highcharts has series.searchPoint function which is used internally to find the points based on some events (click, mousemove, etc.). However, it does not compare points graphic attributes such as markers - so you wont be able to achieve what you want. I think currently the only way to do it is to find the points and check if the markers overlap on your own. The information about the marker can be accessed via point.graphic.

Comment: thanks @morganfree, I'd come to this conclusion and it's good to have someone agree. I'll post my approach if I get it figured out.